# What does "change" on the Stack Exchange leaderboard mean?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, reputation-leagues

I was just looking at the Stack Exchange leaderboards, and noticed that I have negative "change". However, I have definitely not [lost 808 reputation this quarter](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/quarter/stackoverflow/2013-01-01/1008938?sort=reputationchange#1008938). What does this value mean?

Comment: Your *position* on the leaderboard changed; you dropped 808 places compared to the previous period. You gained 592 points in rep so far this quarter.

Comment: For next time, it's helpful if you included a link to the leaderboard entry that you are worried about. I added it for you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Sorry. Thanks for adding it for me!

Comment: Your previous quarter position was [#2447](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/quarter/stackoverflow/2012-10-01/1008938?sort=reputationchange#1008938), right now you are at #3255. 2447 - 3255 = 808.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Wow. I need to get back my edge! :).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number describes your change in position on the list since the last time the userbase was ranked for that period. In this case you dropped 808 positions from the previous quarter.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'll accept when the time limit is reached.

Answer (score 4):

You are at position #3255, which is 808 places lower than last quarter.

**This quarter:**
[image: this quarter]

Notice that 3255 - 808 = 2447, and that's where you were last month:

**Last quarter:**
[image: last quarter]